# MYSQL:How to count gender and Age Category on Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables Namely `flexcode_info` and `flexcode_rescued`.

**flexcode_info** consist of the following

```
GroupID| ID   | Name         | Gender  | Bday       | Relation
10-11  |  1   | Bob Perez    | Male    | 1980-07-10 | Main
10-11  |  2   | Amy Perez    | Female  | 2000-06-13 | Daugther  
10-22  |  3   | Allysa Mayer | Female  | 1990-01-10 | Main
10-23  |  4   | Dave Peralta | Male    | 2000-01-10 | Main
10-25  |  5   | Evan    Reel | Male    | 1970-03-01 | Main
10-25  |  6   | Arthur Reel  | Male    | 1995-04-20 | Son
```

**flexcode_rescued**

```
GroupID| DateRescue    | Note                  | Location    | 
10-11  |  2017-08-08   |VENDOR                 | DISTRICT I  | 
10-22  |  2017-08-08   |BRINGING SOLVENT       | DISTRICT I  | 
10-23  |  2017-08-08   |PERSON WITH DISABILITY | DISTRICT I  | 
10-25  |  2017-08-09   |SLEEPING ON STREET     | DISTRICT I  |
```

Here is the problem  I want to count all male and females, adult and minor
adult male and Female and Minor male and Female which look like this

```
DateRescue|Male|Female|Minor|Adult|AMale|AFemale| MMale|MFemale
 2017-08-08| 2  |  2   |  0  |  4  |  2  |   2   |   0  |  0 
 2017-08-09| 1  |  1   |  0  |  2  |  2  |  1    |   0  |  0
```

I had already tried multiple select combined for each of it has a where statement but the problem is can joined the daterescue

```
SELECT (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDAY, CURDATE()) <= '17')
       AS MinorCount,

       (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDAY, CURDATE()) >= '18')
       AS AdultCount,

       (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE GENDER = 'MALE')
       AS MaleCount,

       (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE GENDER = 'FEMALE')
       AS FemaleCount,

       (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE GENDER = 'MALE'
       AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDAY, CURDATE()) >= '18')
       AS AdultMaleCount,

       (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE GENDER = 'FEMALE'
       AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDAY, CURDATE()) >= '18')
       AS AdultFemaleCount,
       (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE GENDER = 'MALE'
       AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDAY, CURDATE()) <= '17')
       AS MinorMaleCount,

       (SELECT
         COUNT(id)
       FROM flexcode_info
       LEFT JOIN flexcode_rescued
         ON FLEXCODE_INFO.GROUPID = flexcode_rescued.GROUPID
       WHERE GENDER = 'FEMALE'
       AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDAY, CURDATE()) <= '17')
       AS MinorFemaleCount
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code.

Comment: Hi Usagi Miyamoto can you help me ?here is the code you ask for.

Comment: Try to use CASE here.

Comment: I have tried Select count(id) as totalcount,

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT fr.DateRescue,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN fi.Gender = 'Male' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Male,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN fi.Gender = 'Female' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Female,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN (2017 - YEAR(fi.Bday)) < 18 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Minor,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN (2017 - YEAR(fi.Bday)) >= 18 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Adult,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN fi.Gender = 'Male'
                 AND (2017 - YEAR(fi.Bday)) >= 18 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS AMale,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN fi.Gender = 'Female'
                 AND (2017 - YEAR(fi.Bday)) >= 18 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS AFemale,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN fi.Gender = 'Male'
                 AND (2017 - YEAR(fi.Bday)) < 18 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS MMale,
   SUM( CASE
            WHEN fi.Gender = 'Female'
                 AND (2017 - YEAR(fi.Bday)) < 18 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS MFemale
FROM flexcode_Info AS fi
INNER JOIN flexcode_rescued AS fr ON fr.GROUPID = fi.GROUPID
GROUP BY fr.DateRescue
```

Here you can find a demo I made with these data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78380/8

Comment: i have tried this query but the problem is the left join it  doubles the count of each due groupid  . the solution is to distinct it but it ruins the whole process

Comment: @DeanAndrewVega - Try using INNER JOIN to get distinct results. Also check updated answer with the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8043a/1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DateRescued,
       COUNT(NULLIF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, i.BDay, CURRENT_DATE) <= 17,FALSE)) AS MinorCount,
       COUNT(NULLIF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, i.BDay, CURRENT_DATE) >= 18,FALSE)) AS AdultCount,

       COUNT(NULLIF(Gender, 'FEMALE')) AS MaleCount,
       COUNT(NULLIF(Gender, 'MALE')) AS FemaleCount,

       COUNT(NULLIF(Gender = 'MALE' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, i.BDay, CURRENT_DATE) >= 18, FALSE)) AS AdultMaleCount,
       COUNT(NULLIF(Gender = 'FEMALE' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, i.BDay, CURRENT_DATE) >= 18, FALSE)) AS AdultFemaleCount,

       COUNT(NULLIF(Gender = 'MALE' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, i.BDay, CURRENT_DATE) <= 17,FALSE)) AS MinorMaleCount,
       COUNT(NULLIF(Gender = 'FEMALE' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, i.BDay, CURRENT_DATE) <= 17, FALSE)) AS MinorFemaleCount
FROM flexcode_info i
JOIN flexcode_rescued r ON i.GroupId = r.GroupId
GROUP BY DateRescued
```

Comment: i have tried this query but the problem is the left join it doubles the count of each due groupid . the solution is to distinct it but it ruins the whole process